# adding elements in a list to another list

Tags: java, arraylist

First I have two strings.

```
String name = "my name is";
String address = "my address is";
```

Then I want to split the 'name' string value from the space character and add to a list.

```
List word_list = new ArrayList();
word_list.add(Arrays.asList(name.split(" ")));
```

Then similarly I want to split the 'address' string value and add to the same 'word_list'.

```
word_list.add(Arrays.asList(address.split(" ")));
```

From this finally what I get is,

```
[[my, name, is],  [my, address, is]]
```

But what I want is,

```
[my, name, is, my, address, is]
```

Is there any shorter method other than writing a loop to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `addAll` :

```
word_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(name.split(" ")));
word_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(address.split(" ")));
```

[add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) treats the argument as a single element to be added to the list. [addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) expects a `Collection` of elements to be added to the list.

BTW, if you defined your list as `List<String> word_list = new ArrayList<String>();`, the compiler would have prevented you from calling `add` with a `List` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function that does what you want:

```
public String[] mergeArrays(String[] mainArray, String[] addArray) {
    String[] finalArray = new String[mainArray.length + addArray.length];
    System.arraycopy(mainArray, 0, finalArray, 0, mainArray.length);
    System.arraycopy(addArray, 0, finalArray, mainArray.length, addArray.length);

    return finalArray;
}
```

By the way, Apache Commons Lang Lib has a one-line function to do that:

```
[ArrayUtils.addAll(T\[\], T...)][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code.

- Your `word_list` is not generic. You should declare and initialize it as:

`List<String> word_list = new ArrayList<String>();`

... or optionally use the diamond syntax from Java 7 on:

```
List<String> word_list = new ArrayList<>();
```

This way, you ensure type safety, as in, compile-time checks on what gets in (we want `String`s).

- Since your `List` is not generic, it will take any `Object`. In this case, you are `add`ing a `List<String>`, not a `String`

Instead, use `word_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(name.split(" ")))`